# Using list extensions how to check if value exists and I am not out of range?

Tags: c#, linq

I have some list of strings:

```
List<String> text =  new List<String>();
```

at some point I want to access to one of the items of the list using index.

For example:

```
 string str = text[5];
```

My question is with help of list extensions can I check if value exists in specific item and I am not out of range? If index out of range I want to get empty string otherwise I want to get item from list.

Comment: Are you looking for `ElementAtOrDefault`? `string str = text.ElementAtOrDefault(5);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using LINQ's [`ElementAtOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementatordefault) method:

```
string str = text.ElementAtOrDefault(5) ?? string.Empty;
```

This returns the element at the 5th position or the default value for `List`'s type.
Since the default value of `string` is null, use the null-coalescing operator (`??`) to receive an empty string instead.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for

```
  string str = text.ElementAtOrDefault(5);
```

so `str` contains a value or `null` if index (`5`) is out of range. In case you want some other (not `null`) default value

```
  string str = text.ElementAtOrDefault(5) ?? "MyDefaultValue";
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `ElementAtOrDefault()` linq extension method.

This method returns the element at a specified index in a sequence or a default value if the index is out of range.

```
string str = text.ElementAtOrDefault(5);
```

If you want an empty string instead of `null`:

```
string str = text.ElementAtOrDefault(5) ?? string.Empty;
```